# JPQL & Postgresql - How to perform arithmetic on timestamp field for comparison with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, jpa, jpql

I have a table "User" in two environments. One is using an Oracle DB and the other Postgresql. What I would like to do is retrieve all the records created in the last 4 hours. The "User" table has a field "beCreatime" which stores the timestamp of when the record was created.

I've implemented this successfully on the Oracle-based environment using the following:

```
SELECT u.id, u.userName, u.beCreatime FROM User u WHERE u.beCreatime + 4/24 > CURRENT_DATE
```

However, when using the same query on the Postgres environment, I receive the following error:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + integer

Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Position: 100

Error Code: 0

Call: SELECT Id AS a1, UserName AS a2, be_creatime AS a3 FROM BeamUser WHERE ((be_creatime + (? / ?)) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) LIMIT ? OFFSET ?     bind => [4 parameters bound] Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=UserEntity sql="SELECT Id AS a1, UserName AS a2, be_creatime AS a3 FROM BeamUser WHERE ((be_creatime + (? / ?))
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) LIMIT ? OFFSET ?")
```

It seems like Postgres just doesn't like the addition of the timestamp (u.beCreatime) and 4/24. Is there a way to do something similar to this in a Postgres environment?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an interval:

```
WHERE u.beCreatime + interval '4' hour > CURRENT_DATE
```

But you cannot pass the  `'4'` as a paramter, you need to do something like this in a PreparedStatement:

```
WHERE u.beCreatime + (interval '1' hour) * ? > CURRENT_DATE
```

---

Are you *sure* you want to compare that value with `current_date`? Becaues `current_date` does **not** contain any time information in Postgres (as it does in Oracle due to the lack of a "real" `DATE` data type)

If you want to get the Oracle behaviour you have to use `current_timestamp` because unlike Oracle, a `DATE` in Postgres does not contain a time part (that includes `current_date`)

Comment: I'm using the query `SELECT u.id, u.userName, u.beCreatime FROM UserEntity u WHERE u.beCreatime + interval '4' hour > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and receiving the following error:

`Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8025] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT u.id, u.userName,  u.altId2 UserKey, u.beCreatime FROM UserEntity u WHERE u.altId2 IS NOT NULL and u.beCreatime + interval '4' hour > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP], line 1, column 130: unexpected token ['4'].`